# No such table issues

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to query the data of the second table within my database.

I am able to insert into the database (or am led to believe it is successful)

I have altered the version numbers, but this still seems to have effect at all.

Can anyone see what I have done wrong here?

Currently I'm getting the following error:

Logcat:

```
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flybase2/com.example.flybase2.ViewAppointments}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: appointmentTable: , while compiling: SELECT _id, app_name, app_type, app_time, app_date, app_comments FROM appointmentTable ORDER BY app_name ASC
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: appointmentTable: , while compiling: SELECT _id, app_name, app_type, app_time, app_date, app_comments FROM appointmentTable ORDER BY app_name ASC
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1229)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1184)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1301)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.example.flybase2.DBHandler.getAppointmentsData(DBHandler.java:325)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.example.flybase2.ViewAppointments.onCreate(ViewAppointments.java:34)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-20 20:32:15.076: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
```

Column variables:

```
    public static final String KEY_ROWAPPID = "_appid";
public static final String KEY_NAMEAPP = "app_name";
public static final String KEY_TYPEAPP = "app_type";
public static final String KEY_TIMEAPP = "app_time";
public static final String KEY_DATEAPP = "app_date";
public static final String KEY_COMMENTAPP = "app_comments";
public static final String KEY_ALARM = "app_alarm";
```

Table name and version:

```
private static String DATABASE_TABLEAPP = "appointmentTable";
private static int DATABASE_VERSIONAPP = 1;
```

Heres my on create method:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {


        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_TEL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_COMMENTS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"

                );

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLEAPP + " (" +
                KEY_ROWAPPID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAMEAPP + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_TYPEAPP + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_TIMEAPP + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_DATEAPP + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_COMMENTAPP + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_ALARM + " BOOLEAN NOT NULL);"

                );
```

On upgrade:

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLEAPP);
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

Method used for querying the table:

```
    public Cursor getAppointmentsData() {
        String [] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWAPPID, KEY_NAMEAPP, KEY_TYPEAPP, KEY_TIMEAPP, KEY_DATEAPP, KEY_COMMENTAPP};
        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLEAPP, columns, null, null, null, null, KEY_NAMEAPP + " ASC", null);
        return c;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the first `onCreate( db )` call.

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLEAPP);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you mean remove my onCreate method altogether? As Im sure i cant do this due to the fact it needs an onCreate and onUpgrade.

Comment: Or do you mean increase my version number to upgrade? As I have already tried this and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: I removed the second onCreate but sadly my problem is still there. Any other ideas? As I really dont want to have a separate database.