# No such table error whenever I add some table to my db

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I get this error whenever I add some table to my database. If I delete my game and install it again, I don't get that error, so there is that table. I tried to change database version to 2 instead of 1, but it gets updated but still get the error. What's the problem? Here's logcat:

```
04-17 20:01:08.117: D/szipinf(10494): Initializing inflate state
04-17 20:01:08.217: D/szipinf(10494): Initializing inflate state
04-17 20:01:08.227: D/szipinf(10494): Initializing zlib to inflate
04-17 20:01:10.277: E/DataBaseHelper(10494): database updated
04-17 20:01:10.507: I/Database(10494): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: tblLogicTest
04-17 20:01:10.507: E/DataAdapter(10494): getTestData >>android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tblLogicTest: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tblLogicTest WHERE 1 = 1  ORDER BY _ID ASC
04-17 20:01:10.507: D/AndroidRuntime(10494): Shutting down VM
04-17 20:01:10.507: W/dalvikvm(10494): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018560)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{rs.androidaplikacije.themostcompleteiqtest/rs.androidaplikacije.themostcompleteiqtest.LogicTest}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tblLogicTest: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tblLogicTest WHERE 1 = 1  ORDER BY _ID ASC
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: tblLogicTest: , while compiling: SELECT * FROM tblLogicTest WHERE 1 = 1  ORDER BY _ID ASC
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at rs.androidaplikacije.themostcompleteiqtest.TestAdapter.getTestDataLogic(TestAdapter.)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at rs.androidaplikacije.themostcompleteiqtest.LogicTest.nextQuestion(LogicTest.)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at rs.androidaplikacije.themostcompleteiqtest.LogicTest.onCreate(LogicTest.java:93)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.)
04-17 20:01:10.527: E/AndroidRuntime(10494):    ... 11 more
```

Database helper:

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window
//destination path (location) of our database on device
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/rs.androidaplikacije.themostcompleteiqtest/databases/"; 
private static String DB_NAME ="pitanja.sqlite";// Database name
private static SQLiteDatabase mDataBase; 
private final Context mContext;
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

public DataBaseHelper(Context mojContext) 
{
    super(mojContext, DB_NAME, null, 3);// 1 it's Database Version
    DB_PATH = mojContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    this.mContext = mojContext;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException
{
    //If database not exists copy it from the assets


        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();
        try 
        {
            //Copy the database from assests
            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
            throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
        }
    }

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
public boolean checkDataBase(){

SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

try{
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}catch(SQLiteException e){

//database does't exist yet.

}

if(checkDB != null){

checkDB.close();

}

return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
    /*Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name
    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
        return dbFile.exists();
    }
    */

    //Copy the database from assets
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
        {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    //Open the database, so we can query it
    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
    {
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //Log.v("mPath", mPath);
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        //mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }
    @Override
    public void close() 
    {
        if(mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        try {
            // delete existing?

            // Copy the db from assests
            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "database updated");
        } catch (IOException mIOException) {
            Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString());
            try {
                throw mIOException;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Adapter:

```
public class TestAdapter 
{
    protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter";

    private final Context mContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
    private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper;

    public TestAdapter(Context context) 
    {
        this.mContext = context;
        mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext);
    }

    public TestAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException 
    {
        try 
        {
            mDbHelper.createDataBase();
        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase");
            throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase");
        }
        return this;
    }

    public TestAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        try 
        {
            mDbHelper.openDataBase();
            mDbHelper.close();
            mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        } 
        catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "open >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
            throw mSQLException;
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void close() 
    {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

     public Cursor getTestDataMDPI(String whereClause)
     {;
         try
         {
             String sql ="SELECT * FROM tblPitanjaDanskaMDPI WHERE 1 = 1 " + whereClause + " ORDER BY _ID ASC";

             Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
             if (mCur!=null)
             {
                mCur.moveToNext();
             }
             return mCur;
         }
         catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
         {
             Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
             throw mSQLException;
         }
     }
     public Cursor getTestDataHDPI(String whereClause)
     {;
         try
         {
             String sql ="SELECT * FROM tblPitanjaDanskaHDPI WHERE 1 = 1 " + whereClause + " ORDER BY _ID ASC";

             Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
             if (mCur!=null)
             {
                mCur.moveToNext();
             }
             return mCur;
         }
         catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
         {
             Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
             throw mSQLException;
         }
     }
     public Cursor getTestDataLogic(String whereClause)
     {;
         try
         {
             String sql ="SELECT * FROM tblLogicTest WHERE 1 = 1 " + whereClause + " ORDER BY _ID ASC";

             Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null);
             if (mCur!=null)
             {
                mCur.moveToNext();
             }
             return mCur;
         }
         catch (SQLException mSQLException) 
         {
             Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString());
             throw mSQLException;
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: If the table exist and the table name is correct then check whether you are using the correct database name? Like other share the code to help. Also check whether this link solves your problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14429038/no-such-table-issues?rq=1

Comment: Posted my code. Well, it's the same code before and after deinstalling my app from the phone, and it's working after deinstalling and installing again. If I install it over my installed app, it's not working.

Comment: @marjanbaz im not familiar with android's path syntax, but most OS use \ instead of / for path. Java also requires two slashes for path.

Comment: That's all working fine, it does not work only if I add another table to my existing database. And even that works if I uninstall my game from the phone and install it again.

Comment: So the problem arises only from the second time you run it?

Comment: Well, no. Scenario: I have that game installed on my phone, now I've updated my database by adding a table, I then import that db to my assets folder, and run that app on my phone and bam, I get that error.

Comment: It's the same table. I did not change A THING in my code, just added a new table in my database, and added public Cursor getTestDataLogic method in my testadapter class.

Comment: Perhaps theres a clash between the different OS?

Answer (score 0):

Then `onUpgrade` method will not be called unless you increase the database version.

Comment: I did increase it, and it says Updated in logcat but still get the error.

Comment: Can someone help with this??