# How should my onUpgrade() method look like?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

You can see my database helper class below. I use prepopulated sqlite database imported in assets folder. Whenever I add a table to my existing database, I get no such table error if my app is already installed on my phone. I guess my onUpgrade() method is now so good. It works, don't get me wrong, when I change some data to existing tables, I increase db version and it gets updated. But if I add a table I get error.

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
private static String TAG = "DataBaseHelper"; // Tag just for the LogCat window
//destination path (location) of our database on device
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/rs.androidaplikacije.themostcompleteiqtest/databases/"; 
private static String DB_NAME ="pitanja.sqlite";// Database name
private static SQLiteDatabase mDataBase; 
private final Context mContext;
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

public DataBaseHelper(Context mojContext) 
{
    super(mojContext, DB_NAME, null, 3);// 1 it's Database Version
    DB_PATH = mojContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    this.mContext = mojContext;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException
{
    //If database not exists copy it from the assets


        this.getReadableDatabase();
        this.close();
        try 
        {
            //Copy the database from assests
            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "createDatabase database created");
        } 
        catch (IOException mIOException) 
        {
            throw new Error("ErrorCopyingDataBase");
        }
    }

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
public boolean checkDataBase(){

SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

try{
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}catch(SQLiteException e){

//database does't exist yet.

}

if(checkDB != null){

checkDB.close();

}

return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}
    /*Check that the database exists here: /data/data/your package/databases/Da Name
    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        //Log.v("dbFile", dbFile + "   "+ dbFile.exists());
        return dbFile.exists();
    }
    */

    //Copy the database from assets
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream mInput = mContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
        byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int mLength;
        while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0)
        {
            mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
        }
        mOutput.flush();
        mOutput.close();
        mInput.close();
    }

    //Open the database, so we can query it
    public boolean openDataBase() throws SQLException
    {
        String mPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //Log.v("mPath", mPath);
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY);
        //mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
        return mDataBase != null;
    }
    @Override
    public void close() 
    {
        if(mDataBase != null)
            mDataBase.close();
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
        }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        try {
            // delete existing?

            // Copy the db from assests
            copyDataBase();
            Log.e(TAG, "database updated");
        } catch (IOException mIOException) {
            Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString());
            try {
                throw mIOException;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's 2 ways to do onUpgrade, depending on your app.

1)Drop all your old tables, then run onCreate.  THis basically wipes out all your old data and starts over.  Its a good technique if you can regenerate the old data somehow, or just don't care about it.

2)Carefully maintain a diff of your schema between each released version, and write SQL statements to make the proper changes between them-  add new tables, alter existing tables to add/remove columns, etc.  This is time consuming and fragile, so use this only if you need to keep data between those versions.

Comment: So, how to do the first thing? Should I remove all my code from onUpgrade? Is it good at all?

Comment: So you're copying it from the assets dir.  THat's basically taking my path #1, but starting with a predefined db.  The idea is sound, I don't see any glaring defects in your code.  What's the exact error you get?  And when you say add a table-  do you add it to the db in the assets file, or just in code?  Because if its just code, you may try to read/write from that table before you create it, which is obviously an error.  Its best to have every table created in the db in your assets file if you do things this way.

Comment: [You can see the error here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16067152/no-such-table-error-whenever-i-add-some-table-to-my-db). I add the table over SQLite Manager Firefox addon, to the database in the assets file.

Comment: That error means the table doesn't exist.  Are you sure it is being saved to the db in assets-  that you didn't forget to commit a transaction?  Also that the db in assets is up to date-  have you tried a make clean?

Comment: Well, it sure does exist, cause when I uninstall app from the phone and install ti again it works, so the table is there.

Comment: Can someone help me with this??